# Writing the Content-Length header to the client from the server in Tornado

Tags: python, http, http-headers, tornado

I have a tornado server, that simply prints the headers that the client sent.
server.py :

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.httputil as hutil

def handle_request(request):

    message = ""
    try :
            message = request.headers['Content-Length']
    except KeyError :
            message = request.headers
    request.connection.write_headers(
            tornado.httputil.ResponseStartLine('HTTP/1.1', 200, 'OK'),
            tornado.httputil.HTTPHeaders
            ({"Content-Length": str(len(message))}))
    request.connection.finish()
    print(request.headers)

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(handle_request)
http_server.listen(8888, address='127.0.0.1')
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

When I send request to this server using curl, I get the following traceback.

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 234, in _read_message
    delegate.finish()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 280, in finish
    self.server.request_callback(self.request)
  File "Tests/tornado_server.py", line 17, in handle_request
    request.connection.finish()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 430, in finish
    self._expected_content_remaining)
HTTPOutputError: Tried to write 5 bytes less than Content-Length
```

The headers that I sent from Curl :

```
{'Host': '127.0.0.1:8888', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36'}
```

Is it necessary that I should write back the same amount of data as Content-Length ? If so why and how should that be done ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write back the same number of bytes as you say you will. You returned a `Content-Length` header for the *response*. That means your response *body* needs to contain that many bytes.

By the looks of it you don't write *anything* back for a response body; if you are stating that you are sending `len(str(message))` bytes, you probably wanted to send `str(message)` too:

```
request.connection.write(str(message))
```

This is *separate* from the `Content-Length` in the *request*, which denotes how many bytes the request body contains.

Comment: Thanks ! There was another error as well, the header should've been
{"Content-Length": str(len(str(message)))}

Comment: @Sentient07: right, I'm not *that* familiar with Tornado; if `HTTPHeaders` objects don't convert values to strings for you automatically then indeed you'll need to do it explicitly.

Comment: Also note that Tornado will set Content-Length for you in most cases so you don't have to set it yourself. You only need to set Content-Length explicitly if you're streaming the response (i.e. calling self.flush()) and you want the client to know how big the download is instead of using chunked encoding.